# Remove Windows 8 build of app from Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store

I have had a Windows 8 build associated with my app, say with version 1.0.4. I also have an active 1.3.4 version which targets Windows 10. I wanted to make the 1.0.4 build unavailable so I removed it. But it still appears in the Windows Store on Windows 8 devices. Then I read that I need to submit an update and change the pricing & availability. But I don't see a way to do that without also removing the 1.3.4 version from the Windows Store. Any ideas?

EDIT: I added an image of the dashboard which shows which packages are installed. The Windows 8 package is still available even though it is not visible in the dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, can I  understand that your app has two packages, one version is 1.0.4 that targets Windows 8, another version is 1.3.4 that targets Windows 10, and you just want to make the package version 1.0.4 unavailable, am I right?

I suggest you to remove package version 1.0.4 from the submission and you don’t need to change the pricing & availability, after the update is published(new submission submitted in the store), no new customer on Windows 8 will be able to acquire the app(though customer who already have is can continue to use it). The app will still available for new customer on Windows 10.
More detailed info, please refer to [guidance for app package management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/guidance-for-app-package-management)

In addition, there are just Windows Phone store and Windows Store now, please note it.

Comment: Strangely enough, the app is still visible in the store, even though I've removed the Windows 8 package. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you used a different identity for Windows 10?

Comment: You mean the publisher identifier?